# How to render the JSON file in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have the JSON file like this

```json
[{
  "amenity": ["bar", "restaurant", "college", "library", "school", "university", "atm", "bank", "clinic", "hospital", "pharmacy", "nursing_home", "cinema", "embassy", "fire_station", "police", "post_office", "toilets", ""],
  "Buildings": ["yes", "apartments", "bungalow", "hotel", "house", "residential", "commercial", "supermarket", "school", "religious", "hospital", "government", "college"],
  "highway": ["motorway", "trunk", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "unclassified", "residential", "pedestrian", "footway", "path", "bus_stop"]
}]
```

I need to display this JSON file in the react component. I need to display two select option in the first one I need to select anyone of the 3 key like amenity, buildings, highway in the second one I need to display the corresponding values of array in the second object

Comment: What have you tried? Include relevant React component class code.

Comment: I have tried using React functional component

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in React. You just need to render the first list via the keys from the first object. As for the second drop-down, use the currently selected category.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const fetchData = () => Promise.resolve([{
  "amenity": ["bar", "restaurant", "college", "library", "school", "university", "atm", "bank", "clinic", "hospital", "pharmacy", "nursing_home", "cinema", "embassy", "fire_station", "police", "post_office", "toilets", ""],
  "building": ["yes", "apartments", "bungalow", "hotel", "house", "residential", "commercial", "supermarket", "school", "religious", "hospital", "government", "college"],
  "highway": ["motorway", "trunk", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "unclassified", "residential", "pedestrian", "footway", "path", "bus_stop"]
}]);


const App = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  const changeSelection = (e) => setSelected(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => fetchData().then(json => setData(json)), []);

  const [categories = {}] = data, types = categories[selected] || [];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={changeSelection}>{
        ['', ...Object.keys(categories)].map(cat => (
          <option value={cat} selected={selected === cat}>{cat}</option>
        ))
      }</select>
      <select>{types.map(type => (<option value={type}>{type}</option>))}</select>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```